# Piglatin, difficulty understanding how to move a '.' in a String

Tags: java, string, substring, charat

I am having great difficulty with this program I am writing for my computer science class. I've gone through and looked at other programs that students have posted, here and on other sites, but I haven't been been able to understand what I am doing wrong.  I have looked at the Java oracle doc's and it's just not clicking with me.

My main problem is the nested section if statement that should move the '.' to the end of the sentence after adding "ay" to the word. The application isn't complete. After I can learn how to solve this step I'll move on to capitalization of the first word in the sentence. I just don't understand why I am having difficulty with .substring and .charAt.

Please, explain the answer.

```
    File input = new File ("elab.txt");
    File output = new File ("elab.out");

    //create Scanner
    Scanner in = new Scanner(input);

    //create writer
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(output);

    //VariParty, Part 1
    int count = 0;//Simple counter
    String word;//Scanned word from text file, will be edited
    String original;//Original word, backed up from String "word" before edit
    String original1;//Used in consonants
    String sentence = "";//Declare full sentence

    /* What I will do is scan each word in the text document. The application will display
     * a number for each word for my visual learning pleasure. The counter will be //commented
     * out as to not cause any visual action for the complete application. 
     */


    while(in.hasNext()){//Star while
        word = in.next();//Scans individual word
        word = word.toLowerCase();
        count++;//adds to counter
        original = word.toLowerCase();
        original1 = word.toLowerCase();

        //VariParty, Part 2
        char fl = word.charAt(0);
        char fL = Character.toLowerCase(word.charAt(0));
        char endChar = word.charAt(word.length()-1);


        /* This vowel portion of the application will check each "word" and deduce if "ay"
         * should be added to the end of the word beginning with a vowel. Finally, the code
         * will build onto the sentence string to produce a sentence.
         */

        if (fl == 'a' || fl == 'e' || fl == 'i'|| fl == 'o' || fl == 'u'){//Start if
        word = word + "ay";
        System.out.println(count + " VOW) " + "\"" + original + "\"" + " to " + "\"" + word + "\"" + " ");
        out.print(word + " ");                      
        sentence = sentence + " " + word;           
        }//End if


        /* We will now work towards building a better sentence. Our sentence will not have the
         * audacity to place a period in the middle of the word! Our sentences shall forever be
         * properly defined with a punctuation mark at the end, unless it's an apostrophe.              
         */

            if(word.contains(".")){//Start nested if
                word = word.substring(0,word.length()-1);
                word = word + ".";
                System.out.println(count + " NES VOW) " + "\"" + original + "\"" + " to " + "\"" + word + "\"" + " ");
            }//End nested if


        /* Now we will move the word around and deal with the consonants
         * The else statement will build the proper word by moving the first
         * letter to the end of the sentence, then adding "ay" to the end.
         * The final line will be building onto the sentence string.
         */


        else{//Start else
            word = word.substring(1,word.length());
            original = word;
            word = word + fl + "ay";
            System.out.println(count + " CON) " + "\"" + original1 + "\"" + " to " + "\"" + word + "\"" + " ");
            out.print(word + " ");

            sentence = sentence + " " + word;

        }//End else 
    }//End While

    System.out.println(sentence);
    in.close();//Close Scanner
    out.close();//Close PrintWriter
```

Comment: You could have a look at the source code of http://www.donnelly-house.net/funcrec/piglatin/, which is a pig latin translator. It is in JavaScript, but the basic algorithm is the same.

Comment: Please do not add [solved] messages to your titles here - clicking the tick mark, as you have done, is sufficient. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you should do is to make your program testable.

The main functionality is converting a word into piglatin. Therefore you should define a method that does exactly that:

```
public static String translateWordToPigLatin(String word) {
    ....
    return ...;
}
```

Then, you should write another class called `PigLatinTest`, in which you test this method:

```
public class PigLatinTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        testPigLatin("hello", "ellohay");
        testPigLatin("welcome", "ellcomeway");
        // Add more test cases here.
    }

    private static void testPigLatin(String english, String expectedPigLatin) {
        String actual = translateWordToPigLatin(english);
        if (!expectedPigLatin.equals(actual)) {
            throw new AssertionError("Expected \"" + expectedPigLatin + "\" for \"" + english + "\", got \"" + actual "\".");
        }
    }
}
```

In the `translateWordToPigLatin` method, I called the parameter `word`. This is a strong indication that a '.' doesn't belong there. So what you should really do is to extract all proper words from the line, where a word consists only of letters.

The next bigger method should be called `translateLineToPigLatin(String line)`, and in this method, you should:

1. Start at the beginning of the English line.
2. Copy the characters to the pig latin line until you find a letter.
3. Scan further in the English line until you find no letter anymore.
4. The text between step 2 and step 3 is a word.
5. Convert that word to pig latin.
6. Add the converted word to the pig latin line.
7. Continue scanning the English line where you left off.

Comment: Thank you very much for replying. Friday, in my CSC102 class, we will start learning methods. This has been an exciting problem to solve. I have learned from your post and I do appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

On the line below, Your end index is end of word. so, I am not sure what you are trying to do in this step.

```
word = word.substring(0,word.length()-1);
```

As per the documentation

```
public String substring(int beginIndex,
                    int endIndex)
```

So your step should keep the word same. Is that your problem. I can not comment so adding this as answer...

Also, try using Stringbuffer if you are modifying strings in while loop.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I made changes. I see some serious errors that I made in this. In my mind this should work but it's not. 



`if(word.charAt(word.length()-1) == '.'{`
`word = word.substring(0,word.length()-1);`
`word = word + ".";`

Comment: correction, `if(word.charAt(word.length()-1) == '.'){`

Comment: Strings should be compared using `stringone.equals(string2)` and not using `==` that can be only used for primitives.

Comment: I resolved my situation by changing the values to -3 and I added another nested if and else statement. I do appreciate your replies. Thank you very much.